# NoClassDefFoundError while using toJson with an imported class

Tags: java, maven, gson

I'm using `gson.toJson(a)` where `a` is an object from `class A` importing `class B`.

The result is:  `NoClassDefFoundError : B`

Should I import the package (with maven) containing B in a different way?

Does gson need sources to perform `toJson`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details? Are you running it in the editor, or exporting it as an archive and running it that way?

Most likely you need to re-import your maven sources, however, it seems like GSON has nothing to do with the fact that Java was unable to find class B. I checked your application of toJson and that seems fine.

Please make sure that class B is properly added to your imports, and the library was actually linked to your build path properly.

Feel free to share more code and I can try to give you a better answer.

Comment: Indeed, GSON had nothing to do with the problem. The problem was in my editor but did not appear while running with java -jar. I used mvn clean install (instead of the clean and build automatically done by the editor) and the problem completely disappeared.